# MonogDB Query Help - Subobject query w/ a twist

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to query a collection in mongo that's structured like this...

```
{
  "type":"apple"
  "quality": {
    "1": {
       "owner":"Dan",
       "age":28    
    },
    "2": {
       "owner":"Joe",  
       "age":21      
    }
    "3": {
       "owner":"Bob",  
       "age":29      
    }
  }
}
```

I initially tried `findOne({"quality.owner":"Dan"})` but that failed. Then I realized it needed to be done like `findOne({"quality.1.owner":"Dan"})` ... not what I want.

Is there anyway to put a wildcard in place of the `1` or to perform the query the way I'm intending? I don't know what all the variables will be in the quality objects so I don't think I can do a "sub-object" match either =/

EDIT:

Unfortunately Re-formatting this data is out of the question for the project as the data is being retrieved by a 3rd party API and those index numbers represent "placement" (1st place, 2nd place...)

Comment: Can you "push" the rank/placement down into the objects? Or maintain sorted order of the array by order of rank? If there are no gaps in the ranks given by the API, that should be do-able...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current schema you can't query like you want(`findOne({"quality.owner":"Dan"})`). With embedded documents you can search only with [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29).

But you can redesign your current schema to be like this :

```
{
  "type":"apple"
  "quality": [
    {
       number: 1,
       "owner":"Dan",
       "age":28    
    },
    {
       number: 2,
       "owner":"Joe",  
       "age":21      
    }]
  }
}
```

And then search using dot notation:

```
findOne({"quality.owner":"Dan"})
```

Comment: The `$` positional operator is only used in updates. To find by searching arrays, just omit the segment of the path that corresponds to the array index, as `findOne({"quality.owner": "Dan"})`

Comment: Ok, "You can't" is what I needed to hear =) -- leaving the question open for a little while longer.

Comment: @dcrosta: Yeah it was my mistake, fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielDoezema: Redesign current database schema to make array `quality` will be best solution in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

If you can reformulate your documents to use an array instead of a subdocument in place of the `quality` field, then you can query like you want to. Additionally, you can [efficiently index array member fields or the whole array](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) (i.e. the subdocuments themselves):

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"quality.owner": 1})
db.collection.findOne({"quality.owner": "Dan"})
```

If you convert to using an array, you can then use [the `$` positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) to perform updates on array elements and their members:

```
db.collection.update({"quality.owner": "Dan"}, {$set: {"quality.$.age": 27}})
```

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant -- as in, "you can even use `$` once you convert to arrays." Will update to clarify.